# perl - Why exit code 0 if error file not found, can I make it code 1?

Tags: perl

I have a several logical AND commands and in the middle is a perl command that edits a file in-place.

```
echo before && \
perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g' -i qux && \
echo after
```

If the file does not exist perl will die with "Can't open qux: No such file or directory." But the error code is 0. That is a problem because I don't want the command to continue. In other words 'after' shouldn't print if the file doesn't exist. Why is that happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: you could just `echo before && test -f qux && ...`

Comment: @dsm yeah that seems like a good workaround, thanks

Comment: The interpreter (Perl) is returning to the shell, not the (one-line) program that it executed. There is no reason for it to return anything other than success (0). If you were to invoke a script instead of a one-liner you could have it `exit 1`.

Comment: Another point -- the loop over the input is setup as part of `-p` so the absence of a file is an uncaught exception and you have no control over what happens. You could drop that, like `perl -e '-f qux || exit 1; ...'` and then it will work as expected.  But then of course you'd have to set up `while(<>) { ... }` yourself and things become unwieldy.

Comment: @zdim I am curious is there a reason I can't do `$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {exit 1};` I just tried setting up a while(<>) and the die signal handler isn't called

Comment: The idea of using only `-e` is that you can test for the file (`-f`, `not -z`), since it's not setup in the loop already, and you don't have to go to signals. Then you'd have to loop your self, which isn't too bad -- `while <> {...}` (it reads `ARGV`) or just `@o = map { s/../.../r } <>`.  But then you also have to write the file yourself. So it adds up and solution by [Dave Sherohman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18914/dave-sherohman) is much better. The problem with signal handler is that `-p` does the loop first, while you can't set it in `BEGIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `perl -pe ... < file` instead of `perl -pe ... file`. In this case the shell will already complain if the file does not exist without even invoking perl. But this can not be used together with the `-i` switch.

Or since you want to use the `-i` switch you might check that the file is writable before using it. Not that this checks for `qux` being both file and writable because being only one of these is not enough (maybe one needs to check for readable too).

```
[ -f qux ] && [ -w qux ] && perl -pe ... -i qux
```

Comment: This does, however, change the semantics of the Perl, as the output will be written to STDOUT rather than modifying the file in-place.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: you are right, I did not notice the `-i` switch. I've added another way to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so...

As mentioned in comments to the question, the reason `perl` exits with a 0 is because `perl` itself was successful, even if the code executed by `perl` was not.  In order to get it to exit with a failure, then, we need to find a way to make it `die` (or explicitly `exit` with a non-zero status) if the file can't be opened.

But `perl -p` wraps a loop around your one-liner, so can we do that without having to repeat the test on every line?  Yes, we can!  `perldoc perlrun` tells us that `BEGIN` and `END` blocks allow us to take control before or after the loop executes.

But we still need a way to tell whether the file was successfully opened.  To do that, we need to know the name of the filehandle used by `<>`, which `perldoc perlvar` tells us is called `ARGV`.

But `ARGV` is only (reliably) magical when it's read from, so we can't just test for whether it's defined because (in my quick testing) it's *always* defined, even if the file is missing.  So we have to read from it.  And then the first line is lost.  But that's easily fixed by `seek`ing back to the start of the file.

**TL;DR** and the upshot of all that:

```
echo before && \
perl -pe 'BEGIN { exit 1 unless <> ; seek ARGV,0,0 } s/foo/bar/g' -i qux && \
echo after
```

Note that this still isn't 100% perfect.  It will also `die` if the file exists, but is empty.  Checking `defined <>` doesn't fix this flaw and attempting to `<> ; die unless ARGV` causes `<>` to read from `STDIN` if the file doesn't exist.  If anyone has a way to get it to correctly detect empty files, I'd be very interested to hear about it!

Comment: Ah, that escaped me. I put together a short one-liner with only `-e` but this is better. In my testing `BEGIN { exit 1 if not -f $ARGV[0] or -z $ARGV[0] }` takes care of both cases. Longer, but then there is no need for `seek`.

Comment: Very nice, @Zaid! I didn't know `eof` had that magic. Unfortunately, it still fails to distinguish between empty files and missing files. It's looking like there may not be a way to do that without explicitly using file tests from within the Perl code, as @zdim suggests.

Comment: Yes, I think something like `BEGIN { @ARGV = grep -f && ! -z, @ARGV; exit 1 if eof() || ! @ARGV }` would address that, but the solution is an eyesore to say the least. I think it is best to defer these sorts of file checks to the shell if possible, in which case there is no need for the `BEGIN` block at all. Still, this question made for an interesting exercise.

Comment: @Zaid Yes, exactly. I really had a lot of fun tracking down the solution in my answer!